# SimpleStorage always returns 0

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm trying to repeat that tutorial - https://medium.com/@wagnertrindade/ethereum-compile-deploy-and-interact-with-smart-contracts-e65bd42a1a0

everything looks good, but getter always returns 0.

geth version - 1.8.11-stable

node started with:
`geth --rpc --rpcport "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "~/node" --port "30303" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --identity "zero" --networkid 733 mine`

genesis.json: 
`{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 42,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc": {
        "1da3639d184d47f380f8428957bffc09a3914679": {
            "balance": "20000000000000000000"
        }
    }
}`

Smart Contract: StorageExample - https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

What's wrong here?

Comment: The libraries have changed quite a bit since 2017 - try reading the value with a promise, eg contractInst.get().then(function(result) { console.log(result) })

Comment: Thank you, that didn't help. It must have been a workaround problem.